# library resize() in codeigniter not working?

Tags: codeigniter, image-resizing

I'm uploaded image to folder already .Right now i want to resize that image 3 times .First resize image to w:100,h:100,Second resize image to w:200,h:200
,Third resize it to 300:300

Then I'm loaded library for Image Manipulation Class on top in function like this :: $this->load->library('image_lib');

this is my code

```
$picturesData[$key][$key2] = $this->upload->data(); <<< this upload library is usable 

$file_name = $picturesData[$key][$key2]["file_name"];

//explode

$image_name = explode(".", $file_name);


//resize smallImage

$config['image_library'] = 'GD2';

$config['new_image'] = $path."/".$image_name[0]."_sSize";

// รูปที่เอามาใช้ในการ resize

$config['source_image'] = $picturesData[$key][$key2]["file_name"];

$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;

$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;

$config['width'] = 100;

$config['height'] = 100;

//mediumSize

$config['new_image'] = $path."/".$image_name[0]."_mSize";

$config['width'] = 200;

$config['height'] = 200;

//largeSize

$config['new_image'] = $path."/".$image_name[0]."_lSize";

$config['width'] = 300;

$config['height'] = 300;

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);

$this->image_lib->resize();


if(! $this->image_lib->resize()){

  echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();

}
```

this is my error !!
    The path to the image is not correct.

```
Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.

The path to the image is not correct.

Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.

The path to the image is not correct.

Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.

Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.
```

Comment: resize() in codeigniter not working means ?

Comment: it's mean (! $this->image_lib->resize())

Comment: GD Library in not installed on your server so it is giving this error

Answer (score 1):

This seems like working for me.
$config['source_image'] = './image path/pic_name.jpg';

Setup path to source .. exclude the base_url()

Comment: So, do you mean it works for you after excluding the base URL from the path, or regardless of that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$picturesData[$key][$key2] = $this->upload->data(); //this upload library is usable 
$file_name = $picturesData[$key][$key2]["file_name"];
//explode
$image_name = explode(".", $file_name);
//resize smallImage
$config['image_library'] = 'GD2';
$config['new_image'] = $path."/".$image_name[0]."_sSize.".$image_name[1];
//resize
$config['source_image'] = $picturesData[$key][$key2]["file_name"];
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width'] = 100;
$config['height'] = 100;
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();

//mediumSize
$config['new_image'] = $path."/".$image_name[0]."_sSize.".$image_name[1];
$config['width'] = 200;
$config['height'] = 200;
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
//largeSize
$config['new_image'] = $path."/".$image_name[0]."_sSize.".$image_name[1];
$config['width'] = 300;
$config['height'] = 300;
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

Comment: @user2738443: GD library is not installed on your server so it is giving the error. first install GD Library and then try it otherwise try imagemagik for image resizing if imagemagik is installed on your server

Answer (score 0):

continous Girish Sinha answer :: change this $config['source_image'] = $picturesData[$key][$key2]["file_name"]; to $config['source_image'] = $picturesData[$key][$key2]["full_path"];